# Better way to solve this [Int] -> Int -> Int

Tags: list, haskell

Here is an sample problem I'm working upon:

Example Input: `test [4, 1, 5, 6] 6` returns `5`

I'm solving this using this function:

```
test :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
test [] _ = 0
test (x:xs) time = if (time - x) < 0
                   then x
                   else test xs $ time - x
```

Any better way to solve this function (probably using any inbuilt higher order function) ?

Comment: just *imagine* that you have a higher order function which could help solving this problem. what would that higher order function do? can you show us how you would then use it to solve the problem?

Comment: Rather a question than a comment: Isn't the best way of solving this problem the algorithm provided by the TS? I mean, all answers are much more expensive, aren't they?

Comment: @kaan What do you mean by TS ?

Comment: Topic Starter. It's an Interner slang term to refer to you.

Comment: @kaan The other answers don't seem significantly worse to me. What makes you worried?

Comment: @DanielWagner I feel my own solution is better in readable form and efficiency wise good too. :)

Comment: @Sibi I think your code is fine. Nevertheless, decoupling is a good habit to be in, and I think the answers here are giving some ideas on how to think about that effort.

Comment: @DanielWagner, for instance, if we look at jozefg answer:
We have scanl1 that goes through the list, and zip, find and fmap do that all again.
On the other hand, the recursive one goes only one time through the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
test xs time = maybe 0 id . fmap snd . find ((>time) . fst) $ zip sums xs
   where sums =  scanl1 (+) xs
```

or equivalently with that sugary list comprehension

```
 test xs time = headDef 0 $ [v | (s, v) <- zip sums xs, s > time]
      where sums = scanl1 (+) xs
```

`headDef` is provided by [safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.3/docs/Safe.html). It's trivial to implement (`f _ (x:_) = x; f x _ = x`) but the safe package has loads of useful functions like these so it's good to check out.

Which sums the list up to each point and finds the first occurence greater than `time`. `scanl` is a useful function that behaves like `foldl` but keeps intermediate results and `zip` zips two lists into a list of tuples. Then we just use `fmap` and `maybe` to manipulate the `Maybe (Integer, Integer)` to get our result.

This defaults to 0 like yours but I like the version that simply goes to `Maybe Integer` better from a user point of view, to get this simply remove the `maybe 0 id`.

Answer (score 1):

You might like `scanl` and its close relative, `scanl1`. For example:

```
test_ xs time = [curr | (curr, tot) <- zip xs (scanl1 (+) xs), tot > time]
```

This finds all the places where the running sum is greater than `time`. Then you can pick the first one (or `0`) like this:

```
safeHead def xs = head (xs ++ [def])
test xs time = safeHead 0 (test_ xs time)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is verbose, and I don't necessarily recommend writing such a simple function like this (IMO the pattern matching & recursion is plenty clear).  But, here's a pretty declarative pipeline:

```
import Control.Error
import Data.List

deadline :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> a
deadline time = fromMaybe 0 . findDeadline time

findDeadline :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
findDeadline time xs = decayWithDifferences time xs
                   >>= findIndex (< 0)
                   >>= atMay xs

decayWithDifferences :: Num b => b -> [b] -> Maybe [b]
decayWithDifferences time = tailMay . scanl (-) time

-- > deadline 6 [4, 1, 5, 6]
-- 5
```

This documents the code a bit and in principle lets you test a little better, though IMO these functions fit more-or-less into the 'obviously correct' category.

You can verify that it matches your implementation:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

prop_equality :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
prop_equality time xs = test xs time == deadline time xs

-- > quickCheck prop_equality
-- +++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case zipping suggested by others in not quite necessary:

`test xs time = head $ [y-x | (x:y:_) <- tails $ scanl1 (+) $ 0:xs, y > time]++[0]`

Here `scanl1` will produce a list of rolling sums of the list `xs`, starting it with 0. Therefore, `tails` will produce a list with at least one list having two elements for non-empty `xs`. Pattern-matching `(x:y:_)` extracts two elements from each tail of rolling sums, so in effect it enumerates pairs of neighbouring elements in the list of rolling sums. Filtering on the condition, we reconstruct a part of the list that starts with the first element that produces a rolling sum greater than `time`. Then use `headDef 0` as suggested before, or append a `[0]`, so that `head` always returns something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain readability, I would just stick with your current solution. It's easy to understand, and isn't doing anything wrong.

Just because you *can* make it into a one line scan map fold mutant doesn't mean that you *should*!